# how to include to php file with request variable

Tags: javascript, php, variables

This is my index.php:

```
<?php
$num = 20;
include("result.php");

if($result == 'OK')
{
    echo 'The number is true';
}

?>
```

And the result.php:

```
<?php

if($_GET['num'] == 20)
{
    $result = 'OK';
}
else
{
    $result = 'No';
}

?>
```

How i can do this? How can i use `javascript` for this example?
I do not know any thing in javascript. please get me a way for this problem.

Comment: Your question's title and the question itself seem to be contradicting themselves.

Comment: if(isset($_GET['num'])) include("result.php"); is this you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign to `$_GET` just like any other array:

```
$_GET['num'] = 20;
include("result.php");
```

however, that is not recommended, since now `$_GET` no longer actually represents the query string parameters of your request. Is there a reason you can't just use `$num` from within `result.php`?:

```
// If $num isn't set (by index.php), set it from the query string parameter
if ( ! isset( $num ) )
    $num = $_GET['num'];

if($num == 20)
{
    ...
```

Comment: excuse me. I don't understand wat i must to do.